# Background Intelligent Service - Impersonate account

Tags: c#, windows, bit

Platform is Windows 7 and above.

I am having problems with BITS.

I don't even know if this is feasible to do.

I would like to initiate a BITS job under the System account running as a service. I would like to pass in credentials such as NT domain creds domain\Username. I would like the job to transfer (download) from a network share but not while that user is logged on.

So just to re-iterate, Service to download from a network share using BITS but the will need to domain cred to access the share.

I have tried so many different things from impersonating the NT domain account (user isn't logged on and therefore the Job wont start).

Pass credentials into the BITS job but that has little success.

Attempted to add the network share in Credential manager but fails with error 1312

### Update

Some code here for you - I am using the SharpBits as the BITS wrapper. http://sharpbits.codeplex.com/

I have tried to minimise the class to make it as simple as possible. Apologies on posting the code its not as simple as I expected.

```
using SharpBits.Base;
public class BitsFetchFiles : IDisposable
{
    BitsCredentials _BitsCredentials;
    BitsManager mManager = new BitsManager();
    List<string> _JobIds = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo _Source; //Set by constructor
    DirectoryInfo _Cache; //Set by constructor
    
    //Impersonation class to wrap credentials in
    InfoDllImpersonation _Impersonation = null;

    public void GetJob(string Domain, string Username, string Password)
    {
        _BitsCredentials = new BitsCredentials();
        _BitsCredentials.UserName = Domain + "\\" + Username;
        _BitsCredentials.Password = Password;
        _BitsCredentials.AuthenticationTarget = AuthenticationTarget.Server;
        _BitsCredentials.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationScheme.Negotiate;
   
       _Impersonation = new InfoDllImpersonation(Username, Password, Domain);
       
       //Just a method to the impersonated user access to the destination directory
       GiveAllUserAccessToTheFolder(DirectoryDestination);


       BitsJob Bjob = mManager.CreateJob("Service Download", JobType.Download);
       Bjob.OnJobError += Bjob_OnJobError;
       Bjob.OnJobTransferred += Bjob_OnJobTransferred;
       Bjob.Priority = JobPriorityForDownload;
       Bjob.OnJobModified += Bjob_OnJobModified;
       _JobIds.Add(Bjob.JobId.ToString());
       JobInformation.JobId = Bjob.JobId.ToString();
       Bjob.TakeOwnership();

       using (_Impersonation.ImpersonatedUser)
       {
         using (new NetworkConnection(_Source.FullName, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
         _Impersonation.UserName, _Impersonation.Password, _Impersonation.Domain)))
         {
             Bjob.AddCredentials(_BitsCredentials);
             StartIncludingSubs(remoteFiles, Bjob, ref totalFileBytes);
         }
       }
       
      //Enumerate all jobs listed and resume - e.g Bjob.Resume();
      StartAllJobs();
    }

   void StartIncludingSubs(FileInfo[] remoteFiles, BitsJob Bjob, ref long totalFileBytes)
     {
         _LogFile.Log(string.Format("Using network credentials user : {0}",
                       _Impersonation.UserName), LogFile.LogLevel.Debug);


         remoteFiles = _Source.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
         JobInformation.TotalNumberOfFiles = remoteFiles.Length;

         //Collected all remote files...
         JobInformation.StatusInformation =
             "Source Files have been collected and read with a total of "
             + remoteFiles.Length.ToString() + " files";        


         foreach (var fi in remoteFiles)
         {
             string newCacheFile = _Cache + fi.FullName.
                 Substring(_Source.FullName.Length);


             string direct = newCacheFile.Substring(0, newCacheFile.LastIndexOf("\\"));
             Directory.CreateDirectory(direct);
             Bjob.AddFile(fi.FullName, newCacheFile);

             if (_CancelTheJobAddingFiles)
             {                    
                 return;
             }
             //Console.WriteLine("remote file {0} and Local is {1}", _Source.FullName + "\\" + fi.Name, newCacheFile);
             totalFileBytes += fi.Length;
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Would running the service as a Network Service and giving the machine account the permission to read the network share be an option?

Comment: Unfortuneatly not as i pass in different credentials depending on the share

Comment: Have you tried IBackgroundCopyJob2::SetCredentials?  Can you post the code?

Comment: One thought: I'm not sure you should be calling Bjob.AddFile while you're still impersonating.  At what point does it go wrong, and what error(s) occur?